# Github Page using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, github-pages

I have created a static website using Rails (no models, only a view and its corresponding controller). I want it to be deployed on Github Pages, i.e., typing this link on the browser and hitting Enter must show my static website: https://my-username.github.io.

How do I do it?

Comment: Unless you generate the HTML locally or something, I don't think that it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to deploy a static website to GitHub Pages without using Jekyll, you'll need to build the static content locally, and then push it to your GitHub repository [with a `.nojekyll` file](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages#turning-jekyll-off) in the root so GitHub Pages does not try to run Jekyll on it.

More info at the [GitHub Pages docs](https://help.github.com/categories/20/articles).